# Rails 4 confuses one of my engines model's with another engines lib module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have 2 mountable engines named Authorization and People. People has a model named User and Authorization has a nested module Authorization::People::User, I only used for its module functions.

So the issue if that Rails confuses Authorization's People::User with the User model in the People engine.

When I start the server up and visit the path it complains about there not being a constructor and this is further illustrated when I use RSpec and it complains about the absence of a new method. The problems go away when I rename user.rb inside of authorization to a name that doesn't clash. The reason I believe this should not be happening is because the outer module Authorization should prevent any name collisions.

Inside of the Authorization engine's engine.rb file I put the lib directory into the load path like so

```
lib -> authorization -> engine.rb
module Authorization
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Authorization

    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
  end
end
```

This is the module I created to handle authorization
    lib -> authorization -> people -> user.rb

```
module Authorization
  module People
    module User

        #If any of these methods returns true there is an error
        def self.auth_user(editingUser,tokenUser)
            if editingUser != tokenUser
                #Can only edit your own data
                return true
            else
                return false
            end
        end

    end
  end
end
```

This is how I invoke the authorization inside of my user engine

```
::Authorization::People::User.auth_user(@user,@instance_hash["current_user"])
```

There errors may have something to do with the precedence in the load path or
I could be defining my modules incorrectly but I've been racking my brain trying
to figure this one out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Since I was only using the Authorization engine for it's modules, I decided to
make a simple Rails plugin/gem. I would still like a better solution to the name conflict
problem so I won't close the question